# AngularJS - problems passing object to a function in the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call a function in the directive but its not returning anything to the view.

```
app.directive('eventCard', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'html/eventcard.html',
    replace: true,
    scope: {

        eventObject: '=',
        getHashes: '&'
    }
    }

});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope){



$scope.event = {
    datetime: 'FRI, 6 NOV 10:00 AM',
    title: 'Event Title goes here - lalelalela',
    address: {
        road: '650 Address Rd',
        city: 'Toronto',
        state: 'Ontario',
        postal: 'A1B1C3',
        country: 'CA'
    },
    hashes: ['#hash','#hash1','#hash2']
}

$scope.allHashes = function(event){

    var x = event;
    var collect = '';
    var link = '';

    for (i = 0; x.length < i; i++) { 

        //remove #
        link = x[i].substr(1);

        collect += "<a href='#/search/" + link + "'>" + x[i] + "</a>";

    }
        return collect;
    }

}])
```

Custom directive:

```
 <event-card event-object="event" get-hashes="allHashes(hashes)"></event-card>
```

Directive template:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="event-img-area">
    <img src="images/event-img-pholder.png">
</div>
<div class="event-short-info-area">
    <p class="event-time-card">{{ eventObject.datetime }}<br>
    <span class="event-title-card">{{ eventObject.title }}</span></p><br>
    <span class="event-address-card">{{ eventObject.address.road }}, {{ eventObject.address.city }}, {{ eventObject.address.state }}, {{ eventObject.address.postal }}, {{ eventObject.address.country }}</span>
</div>
<div class="event-tags-area clearfix">
    <div class="hash-card"><span class="hashes">{{ allHashes({ hashes: eventObject.hashes }) }}</span></div>
    <div class="bookmark-card"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

i cant figure out what im doing wrong here. i tried everything that i had in mind that could be the problem.

so basically the function is not returning anything to the custom directive template.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be calling getHashes from inside the directive anywhere. Instead, you're trying to call allHashes, which is part of what's being passed into that property.

The way I do this is in my link function I have something like this:

```
getHashesExp = attrs.getHashes;
getHashesFn = $parse(getHashesExp);

scope.doSomething = function doSomething() {
   getHashesFn(scope);
}
```

Then you'd call doSomething() from the template.

Note that I personally don't use camel case or snake case in directive attribute names. I'm pretty sure it's problematic.

Comment: the getHashes is for <event-card event-object="event" get-hashes="allHashes(hashes)"></event-card>

it is reading it properly. i tested in the template.

what im having problems is with the function. its not returning what i want. i will try to do like u did.

Comment: I don't see how you can know if it's returning what you want, since you're not referencing it in the template.

Comment: the getHashes is to find get-hashes in my <event-card></event-card>

then get-hashes="allHashes(hashes) call the function and 1 parameter 

$scope.allHashes = function(event) get called and receive eventObject.hashes

Comment: I don't think you quite understand passing functions around as references. Once you pass in a reference to allHashes into getHashes, you need to call getHashes, not allHashes. allHashes belongs to the outer scope and is not available in the isolate scope. In your code, you are not calling getHashes anywhere.

Comment: Amy, go ahead and try it. or try an answer.

Comment: If you're able to get hold of something in the parent scope, your isolate scope isn't working correctly. Also please note that I did post an answer.

Comment: i found out that my for loop had a stupid mistake. 

about the understanding of functions as reference, i think you have to revise it because it is correct.

thank you for your help anyway.